# How to test that a method gets called twice with different arguments in Python unittest

Tags: python-unittest

Say I have a method that looks like this:

```
from otherModule import B
def A():
    for pair in [[1, 2], [3, 4]]:
        B(*pair)
```

and I have a test that looks like:

```
class TestA(unittest.TestCase):
    @patch("moduleA.B")
    def test_A(self, mockB):
        A()
        mockB.assert_has_calls([
            call(1, 2),
            call(3, 4)
        ])
```

For some reason I get an `AssertionError: Calls not found.` because it only registers teh call with `3,4` twice. Does what I'm doing look right?

Answer (score 2):

It works fine, can't reproduce the error.

E.g.

`moduleA.py`:

```py
from otherModule import B


def A():
    for pair in [[1, 2], [3, 4]]:
        B(*pair)
```

`otherModule.py`:

```py
def B(x, y):
    print(x, y)
```

`test_moduleA.py`:

```py
import unittest
from unittest.mock import patch, call
from moduleA import A


class TestA(unittest.TestCase):
    @patch("moduleA.B")
    def test_A(self, mockB):
        A()
        mockB.assert_has_calls([
            call(1, 2),
            call(3, 4)
        ])


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

unit test results with coverage report:

```sh
.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.001s

OK
Name                                         Stmts   Miss  Cover   Missing
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
src/stackoverflow/59179990/moduleA.py            4      0   100%
src/stackoverflow/59179990/otherModule.py        2      1    50%   2
src/stackoverflow/59179990/test_moduleA.py       9      0   100%
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
TOTAL                                           15      1    93%
```

Python version: `Python 3.7.5`